# Pyramid : How to create a REST Server using @view_defaults and @view_config with classes in separate file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid

I am creating a simple REST server in pyramid by following the [tutorial](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/viewconfig.html#view-defaults-class-decorator). When I write the class and server startup code in same file, it works as expected. But when I move the class file to separate file it is not working.

The following is my project structure.
[image]

The code I have written is

**1. server.py**

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator

from test_view_defaults import RESTView

if __name__ == '__main__':
  with Configurator() as config:
    config.add_route('rest', '/rest')
    config.scan()
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 6543, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

**2. test_view_defaults.py**

```
from pyramid.response import Response
from pyramid.view import view_config
from pyramid.view import view_defaults

@view_defaults(route_name='rest')
class RESTView(object):
  def __init__(self, request):
      self.request = request

  @view_config(request_method='GET')
  def get(self):
      return Response('get')

  @view_config(request_method='POST')
  def post(self):
      return Response('post')

  @view_config(request_method='DELETE')
  def delete(self):
      return Response('delete')
```

When I request `http://localhost:6543/rest` it gives 404 error.
Could anyone help me to find what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem as below

1. Created a directory (module) named 'api'
2. Moved the class file `test_view_defaults.py` into the above created directory
3. Changed the scan method as `config.scan(package='api')`
4. The changed server.py is as follows

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator


if __name__ == '__main__':
  with Configurator() as config:
    config.add_route('rest', '/rest')
    config.scan(package='api')
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 6543, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```